# Service broker takes very high total elapsed time

Tags: sql, sql-server, service-broker

I have recently enabled the service brokers and it's executing without any issue but when I look at the list of current sessions and found two rows in a BACKGROUND state and performing a DELETE command in MSDB.

[image]

Is it safe to have very high total elapsed time for service brokers?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you have an activation procedure that issues a `waitfor` within it. Good... that is how you're supposed to do it. But, while it's waiting for a message to process on the queue, it's going to be showing that wait type. If you don't want it to wait indefinitely, you can put add a `timeout` clause on the `waitfor` statement; something in the order of minutes seems reasonable to me.

Comment: You suspected right, but if I will add a timeout of 5 minutes then it will start the process when a new message receives, right?

Comment: The short answer is: yes. But let's step back for a minute. What problem are you having with the way it's currently running?

Comment: I understood it but my boss asking me why it's showing high total elapsed time, he is always checking the current list of session so there will not be an issue with the performance. Thanks!